# How to change element visibility according to parent element size

Tags: css, web, responsive-design

I'm looking for a solution similar to media queries, that will work according to element size **rather than viewport size**. for example :

---

DIV A is visible for containers with minimum 400px width
[image]

---

DIV A is hidden when it's parent element width is less than 400 px
[image]

Can this be done without using JavaScript?

Comment: Do both A and B have minimum widths?

Comment: quite simply, it cannot - you have to make use of javascript for this

Comment: That's what I thought ... I'm looking for a hack, or other creative solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use a media query in your css file maybe:

```
@media (max-width 399px) {
    .divA {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

This should work if the parent div is the width of the screen (ie a container). Otherwise you would probably need to use javascript. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes this is exactly the issue I'm facing. I guess JS is the solution